# Wong, An Introduction to Pseudo-Differential Operators. Exercise 4.1.

Tags: functional-analysis

[Wong, An Introduction to Pseudo-Differential Operators]

Exercise 4.1. Here is another elegant proof of Proposition 4.5.

(i) Let $\varphi$ be the function defined on $\mathbb{R}$ by
\begin{equation} \varphi(x)=e^{-x^2/2},\quad x\in\mathbb{R}\end{equation}
Let $y=\widehat{\varphi}$. Prove that
\begin{equation} y'(\xi)+\xi y(\xi)=0,\quad \xi\in\mathbb{R}.\end{equation}

(ii) Use the result in part (i) to prove that
\begin{equation} \widehat{\varphi}(\xi)=e^{-\xi^2/2},\quad \xi\in\mathbb{R}.\end{equation}

How proves (i)? My attempt:

\begin{eqnarray}
y'(\xi)&=&\frac{d}{d\xi}\int e^{-i x\xi}\varphi(x)dx\\
&=&\int (-x)e^{-ix\xi}\varphi(x)dx\\
&=&\int e^{-ix\xi}(-x)\varphi(x)dx\\
&=&\widehat{(-x)\varphi}(\xi)
\end{eqnarray}

Therefore $y'(\xi)+\xi y(\xi)=\widehat{(-x)\varphi}(\xi)+\xi\widehat{\varphi}(\xi)$ and I would like $\widehat{(-x)\varphi}(\xi)=(-\xi)\widehat{\varphi}(\xi)$ to have the result ...

Comment: You're missing a factor of $i$. You should have $$\frac{dy}{d\xi}=i\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{-ix\xi}\big[-x\varphi(x)\big]dx$$ Note $-x\varphi(x)=\varphi'(x)$ which reveals $y'(\xi)$ is the Fourier transform of $\varphi'(x)$. Now use the well know property that $\mathcal{F}(\varphi'(x))=i\xi \widehat{\varphi}(\xi)$ to get your desired result.

Comment: very very thanks